# graphql: how to handle prev page, next page, last page and first page properly?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, graphql, relay

For frontend I am using React + Relay. I have some connection at the backend that could be queried like:

```
query Query {
    node(id: 123456) {
        teams(first: 10) {
            node {
                id
                name
            }
            page_info {
                start_cursor
                end_cursor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for the traditional approach, I can use `skip PAGE_SIZE * curr limit PAGE_SIZE` to query for next page, prev page and first page and last page (In fact I can query for random page)

But how should I implement the frontend to make these requests elegantly?

Comment: Your schema doesn't seem to be compliant with the relay spec. You are supposed to have `myConnection.edges.node`, `myConnection.pageInfo` and not `page_info`. You probably want to check out the example of createPaginationContainer. https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/pagination-container.html#pagination-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Junchao, what Vincent said is correct. Also, you must have a re-fetch query and send `refetchVariables` with your `first` value updated. I will try to provide you an example:

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  TeamsComponent,
  {
    query: graphql`
      fragment TeamsComponent_query on Query
        @argumentDefinitions(
          first: { type: Int }
          last: { type: Int }
          before: { type: String }
          after: { type: String }
        ) {
        teams(
          id: { type: "ID!" }
          first: { type: Int }
          last: { type: Int }
          before: { type: String }
          after: { type: String }
        ) @connection(key: "TeamsComponent_teams", filters: []) {
          count
          pageInfo {
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
          }
          edges {
            node {
              id
               name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
  graphql`
    query TeamsComponent(
      $after: String
      $before: String
      $first: Int
      $last: Int
    ) {
        ...TeamsComponent_query
          @arguments(
            first: $first
            last: $last
            after: $after
            before: $before
          )
    }
  `,
);
```

I tried to build an example based on your code. This is basically the idea. The bottom query is the re-fetch one. Alongside with that, you must trigger this re-fetch somehow by calling `this.props.relay.refetch` passing your `renderVaribles`. Take a deep looker into the docs about this.
Hope is helps :)

UPDATE:

Just to add something, you could have a `handleLoadMore` function with something like this:

```
  handleLoadMore = () => {
    const { relay, connection } = this.props;
    const { isFetching } = this.state;

    if (!connection) return;

    const { edges, pageInfo } = connection;

    if (!pageInfo.hasNextPage) return;

    const total = edges.length + TOTAL_REFETCH_ITEMS;

    const fragmentRenderVariables = this.getRenderVariables() || {};
    const renderVariables = { first: total, ...fragmentRenderVariables };

    if (isFetching) {
      // do not loadMore if it is still loading more or searching
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      isFetching: true,
    });
    const refetchVariables = fragmentVariables => ({
      first: TOTAL_REFETCH_ITEMS,
      after: pageInfo.endCursor,
    });

    relay.refetch(
      refetchVariables,
      null,
      () => {
        this.setState({ isFetching: false });
      },
      {
        force: false,
      },
    );
  };
```

UPDATE 2:

For going backwards, you could have something like:

```
  loadPageBackwardsVars = () => {
    const { connection, quantityPerPage } = this.props;
    const { quantity } = getFormatedQuery(location);

    const { endCursorOffset, startCursorOffset } = connection;

    const firstItem = connection.edges.slice(startCursorOffset, endCursorOffset)[0].cursor;

    const refetchVariables = fragmentVariables => ({
      ...fragmentVariables,
      ...this.getFragmentVariables(),
      last: parseInt(quantity || quantityPerPage, 10) || 10,
      first: null,
      before: firstItem,
    });

    return refetchVariables;
  };
```

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer -- though I think the example u give is still fetching next page right? What about prev page, first page and last page?

Comment: Not sure if could provide all examples and cases but I updated with an idea for going backwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help -- I can take a closer look at the container. But seems fundamentally the idea is what I am doing now. Manipulating different variables

Comment: In my opinion, Relay is very hard. I still don't get it everything, but at the same time, I think it's very powerful. Good luck :)